# phalcon のCriteriaのbetweenWhereはautobindなんでしょうか？

Tags: php

どうやって確認していいのかわからず、専門家の知見を拝借させてください。

仕事でphalconを使い始めました。英語マニュアルと格闘しながらModel周りを作っているのですが、例えばこんなコードではbindがうまく動いてくれませんでした。

```
$criteria = self::query();
$criteria->betweenWhere('created', ":start:", ":end:");
$criteria->bind(array("start" => $start, "end" => $end));
$criteria->bindTypes(
    array("start"=>Column::TYPE_DATETIME,"end"=>Column::TYPE_DATETIME)
);
$row = $criteria->execute();
```

実行時のエラー

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in
```

ですが、以下のコードであれば正常に動作します。

```
$criteria = self::query();
$criteria->where('created between :start: and :end:');
$criteria->bind(array("start" => $start, "end" => $end));
$row = $criteria->execute();
```

で、これも動きます

```
$criteria = self::query();
$criteria->betweenWhere('created', $start, $end);
$row = $criteria->execute();
```

これはつまり、betweenWhereはautobindしてくれているということでしょうか？
であればSQLインジェクション対策としてそれに頼りたいと思うのですが、
実際のところどうなんでしょうか？
ご教授くださいm(__)m

Answer (score 1):

自動バインドされている、というドキュメントの記述は見つけられませんでしたが、 Phalcon のソースコードを見たところ、次のような PHP コードと対応するようです。

```
$minimumKey = ...; $maxmumKey = ...;

$criteria->andWhere(
    $expr . " BETWEEN :" . $minimumKey . ": AND :" . $maximumKey . ":",
    [$minimumKey => $minimum, $maximumKey => $maximum]
);
```

Zephier という PHP に似た言語で書かれているので、比較的読みやすいかと思います。

https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/phalcon-v2.0.2/phalcon/mvc/model/criteria.zep#L381

Comment: 早速の回答有難うございます！隣席同僚と共に感謝です。よくわかりました。出典まで示して下さってより成長できそうです。